# Are distinct powers of an element in a torsion-free semigroup unique?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a torsion-free abelian semigroup. Prove that distinct powers of $x$ are unique for all $x\in\mathcal{G}$.

I've seen several proofs for finite groups, but I'm wondering if it's possible to generalize into infinite torsion-free groups.

Comment: What is the definition of a torsion-free semigroup?

Comment: "distinct powers of $x$ are unique": is this an awkward way to say that $n\mapsto x^n$ is injective (as a map $\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{G}$)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's true. Consider the semigroup on $2$  elements $\{1,a\}$ with $1\cdot a = a\cdot 1 = a$, $a\cdot a = a$.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense, because you have $e=1$, but then $a\cdot a=a$ implies $e=a$.